# Regex restricting 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I went through many threads and there are many answers to the given problem. But some how I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.
My requirement is to not match more than 1 numeric after decimal
and Also non decimal numbers should be discarded.
eg

Valid

```
1.1
12.1
1234.1
123456.0
.1
```

Invalid

```
.12 
123
123.12
```

What I wrote is `^([0-9]?\.?)+\.?[0-9]{1}$`

When I try to match `11.123` or `123` iI get a match. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex works for your use case: `^\d*\.\d$`
WHere `^\d*` match from starting of the string all digits (`*` operator stay for zero or more), then escape `.` with `\.` and finally `\d$` match only if there is one char before the end of the string

Comment: In this regex .1 fails i mean no digit before decimal and one after the decimal is supposed to pass.

Comment: @sameer corrected, I wrongly use `+` instead of `*`. Now it match all the value inside the valid block and doesn't match all the other

Answer (score 0):

This one should do:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9])?$
```